# php - update with PDO not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to update a row in a table in mysql database using PDO and taking the data from a form using post method.

For example this code does not do the job (id taken from session)...

```
$u = $_POST;
if( isset($_POST['update']) ) {
    $output = 'table';
    $usr = "update table set one=?, two=?, three=? where id=?";

    $one=$_POST['one'];
    $two=$_POST['two'];
    $three=$_POST['three'];

    $query=$db->prepare($usr);
    if( !$query->execute(array($one, $two, $three)) ) {
        $db->error;
    } else {
        print "update successful";
    }
}
```

It also doesn't work with four parameters like this:

```
$u = $_POST;
if( isset($_POST['update']) ) {
    $output = 'table';
    $usr = "update table set one=?, two=?, three=? where id=?";

    $one=$_POST['one'];
    $two=$_POST['two'];
    $three=$_POST['three'];
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    $query=$db->prepare($usr);
    if( !$query->execute(array($one, $two, $three, $id)) ) {
        $db->error;
    } else {
        print "update successful";
    }
}
```

This does not work either (again, id taken from session)...

```
$u = $_POST;
if( isset($_POST['update']) ) {
    $output = 'table';
    $usr = "update users set one=:one, two=:two, three=:three where id=?";
    $res = $db->prepare($usr);
    if(!$res->execute(array(':one'=>$u['one'],
                            ':two'=>$u['two'],
                            ':three'=>$u['three']))) {
        $error['usr'] = sprintf("%s could not be updated", htmlentities($_POST['firstname']));
        $output = 'form'; }
    else {
        //$status = sprintf("%s created", htmlentities['firstname']);
    }
}
```

I also tried this http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/insert-update-and-delete-with-pdo/ and it also didn't work...

Comment: Make sure the data is different from the data already in the database. If its the same it will return 0 rows changed

Comment: if I'm updating it means I'm making some changes, no?... just thinking...

Comment: what's happened with one of the answers?...

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to the execute() method aren't the good ones :

For the first example, the number of expected arguments is 4, you only give 3, the id parameter is missing.

For the second, please read the documentation, you musn't set the ":" char in the associative array you give as argument. The id argument is still missing.

Comment: Sorry but in the second case the ":" caracter is necessary or they is no way for PDO to bind the values correctly. The good point with this solution is that order of your binded parameters doesnt matter.

Comment: the first example - adding the fourth parameter (id) doesn't change anything

Comment: Try to print the error ! This line does nothing : $db->error;

Comment: At least, does `$id` variable exists in you script ?

Comment: @Kern & ThinkTank : colon or no colon, it works either way. internally it's stored _with_ the leading colon, but if you leave it out it's just prepended for you.

Comment: @ThinkTank : my bad, it's true that according to the manual, the ":" char must be set. It works also without, but I wonder now if it takes few microseconds more to forget it. Ty !

Comment: ThinkTank - yes, as I wrote above 'id' is taken from session or from the form with $_POST, either way - no success

Comment: Kern, nothing happens if I add a line to print.

Comment: if( !$query->execute(array($one, $two, $three)) ) {
        var_dump($db->error);die;
    } else {
        print "update successful";
    }

Answer (score 0):

you miss `$id` you pass only 3 arguments

try this code :-

```
if( !$query->execute(array($one, $two, $three,$id)) )
```

Comment: update table set one='$one', two='$two', three='$three' where id='$id'

Comment: print this query and run on phpmyadmin @mt_had